# Modules to create file only if it does not exist and write some data

Tags: ansible

I need to use Ansible modules to check if a the file exist, and if it doesn't, then create it and write some data in to it.

If the file exists then check the content, which I am trying to write, is present in that file.

If the content is not present, write the content into it.
If the content is present then do nothing.

My playbook below is not working.
Any suggestions on this?

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: check for file
    stat:
      path: "{{item}}"
    register: File_status
    with_items:
      - /etc/x.conf
      - /etc/y.conf
  - name: Create file
    file:
      path: "{{item}}"
      state: touch
    with_items:
      - /etc/x.conf
      - /etc/y.conf
    when: not File_status.stat.exists
  - name: add content
    blockinfile:
      path: /etc/x.conf
      insertafter:EOF
      block: |
        mydata=something
```

Can you help me with the modules and conditions which can achieve my desired output?

Comment: The last task is enough if you add the [`create: true` option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html#parameter-create)

Comment: @Zeitounator I didn't get you. where should I use create?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will:

- Create the file if it does not exist and report `changed`
- Add the block at the end of file if it does not exists and report `changed`, i.e.

  ```
  # BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
  mydata=something
  mydata2=somethingelse
  # END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
  ```
- Update the block wherever it is in the file if the content changed and report `changed` (see the [`marker` option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html#parameter-marker) if you have several blocks to manage in the same file, and dont forget `{mark}` in there if you change it).
- Do nothing if the block is up-to-date anywhere in the file and report `ok`.

Please read the [module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html) for more info

```yaml
---
- name: blockinfile example
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts:false

  tasks:
    - name: Update/create block if needed. Create file if not exists
      blockinfile:
        path: /tmp/testfile.conf
        block: |
          mydata=something
          mydata2=somethingelse
        create: true
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the possible way to achieve your requirements.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Create file
    copy:
      content: ""
      dest: "{{item}}"
      force: no
    with_items:
      - /etc/x.conf
      - /etc/y.conf

  - name: add content
    blockinfile:
      path: "{{ item.file_name }}"
      insertafter: EOF
      block: |
        "{{ item.content }}"
    loop:
      - { file_name: '/etc/x.conf', content: 'mydata=something' }
      - { file_name: '/etc/y.conf', content: 'mydata=hey something' }
```

Comment: This is not idempotent as it will create an empty file then systematically add the two blocs one after an other each time you run it even if the file already contained the blocs in first place. More over this will delete any other content in the file totally discarding the advantage of running `blockinfile`.